# "client_secret is missing." in iOS Google Sign in

Tags: ios, oauth, google-api, google-signin

I'm trying to integrate Google OAuth2 into my Swift app.
Following [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift) guide, I can install the library and add the button. The google sign in prompt opens, but when I sign in the request fails with 400:

```
Error data:
{
    error = "invalid_request";
    "error_description" = "client_secret is missing.";
}
```

This is my view delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // …

    // Initialize sign-in
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "(xxx).apps.googleusercontent.com"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true
}
```

I have no clue how to set the secret, it's mentioned nowhere in the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that the type of your client in Google Console is showing as "**iOS**". In case you created a Desktop or Web app by mistake, you will see this error.

[image: Google Console showing client type]

Comment: i couldn’t validate this because it’s been years but i’ll assume this fixes the issue

Answer (score -1):

My fix:

1. Go to the pod `GTMOAuth2` in your project (under `Pods`)
2. Open up `GTMOAuth2Authentication.m`
3. Go to the function `authenticationWithServiceProvider`
4. Change `clientSecret` to your secret.
5. Build project

[image]

When I ran `pod install`, GIDSignIn bumped a few versions which caused my code to revert back to the original. Hope this helps!

Comment: On a second note, you shouldn't do this. You should authenticate with your backend server accordingly.